# Help with enums and Enum.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, string, class, enums

I'm new to enum.

I've got this enum:

```
public enum Categories
{
    Animals,
    Animations,
    Accessories,
    Apearance,
    Clothing,
    Gadgets,
    Land,
    Scripts,
    Vehicles,
    Weapons,
    Other
}
```

Then I have this variable: `private Categories Category;`
I'm trying to parse user input (string) so that `Category` will be equal to the right enum.

```
this.Category = Enum.Parse(Categories ,cat);
```

And I get this Error:

```
'Product.Categories' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `typeof(Categories)` instead of `Categories` and add a cast, like this:

```
this.Category = (Categories)Enum.Parse(typeof(Categories), cat);
```

This assumes that `this.Category` is of type `Categories` and is required because [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) returns a value of type, `object`.

Comment: `this.Category` is indeed declared as such :)

Answer (score 4):

To get the `Type` object to use with a method like `Enum.Parse()`, use the `typeof` operator with the type name. You also need to perform a cast from `object` (which it returns) to your enum:

```
this.Category = (Categories) Enum.Parse(typeof(Categories), cat);
```

Comment: To add to the above answer, there is also an example for this on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx#9ad1524e-346d-4e5d-8637-88a5cc1ba98a)